# What is the noun and verb in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, nouns, syntactic-analysis

A student asked me this question and I have no clue.

> In seconds the only evidence that the rats were there at all were the restless lumps under the man's clothes, forever sliding from place to place across him.

Comment: There are several nouns and verbs, and an error (or at least, a debatable point): as *evidence* is singular, the sentence should have "**was** the restless lumps", because the verb has to match its subject rather than its complement. However, I think your question needs more detail about what you are actually after.

Comment: Where does that sentence come from? :)

Comment: It's from a book called Coraline by Neil Gaiman. This is the full sentence. In seconds the only evidence that the rats were there at all were the restless lumps under the man’s clothes, forever sliding from place to place across him; and there was still the largest rat, who stared down, with glittering red eyes, at Coraline from the man’s head.

Comment: The subject (a noun) is *the only evidence*. The verb (a linking verb) is *were*. The subject complement (a noun) is *the restless lumps*. Note that the verb should actually be *was*, to agree with the subject. Remove all the modifiers to see: *the only evidence was the restless lumps*

Comment: @AndrewLeach It works, too. No probs.

Comment: Also @TinfoilHat

Answer (score -2):

> In seconds the only evidence that the rats were there at all were the restless lumps under the man's clothes, forever sliding from place to place across him.

The only evidence the nouns verbed at all verb2 nouns2, forever verb3ing at nouns.

I'm reading verb2/noun2 as the crux of the sentence. The only evidence was (verb) the restless lumps (noun).